# `geom_text()` labels are very light/faint - need them normal/dark

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
# Create the data frame
library(tidyverse)
dat <- read.table(text = "A B C
                          1   23  234 324
                          2   34  534 120
                          3   56  324 124
                          4   34  234 124
                          5   123 534 654",
                  sep = "", 
                  header = TRUE) %>% 
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value") %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  mutate(ind = as.factor(rep(1:5)), 
         perc = value / sum(value)) %>% 
  arrange(variable, -perc) %>% 
  mutate(ordering = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(lab.y = cumsum(perc), 
         lab.y.mid = lab.y - (perc / 2))

# Toggle whether red is on top/bottom with '1L' or '-1L'
red <- 1L
n_ord <- length(unique(dat$ordering))
fill_scale <- c("darkred", rep("black", n_ord - 1L)) %>% 
  setNames(red * seq(n_ord))
alpha_scale <- c(0.5, rep(0.3, n_ord - 1L)) %>% 
  setNames(red * seq(n_ord))
# Plot the data
ggplot(dat, aes(variable, 
                perc, 
                fill = factor(red * ordering), 
                alpha = factor(red * ordering))) + 
  geom_col(color = "white", size = 1.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(guide = "none", values = fill_scale) + 
  scale_alpha_manual(guide = "none", values = alpha_scale) + 
  facet_grid(~ variable, scales = "free_x") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "none") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) + 
  geom_text(aes(y = 1 - lab.y.mid, label = ind), color = "black")
```

[image: light text on plot]

I've been under the assumption that ggplot plots things in sequential order, line-item by line-item. The last line of my ggplot above is:

```
geom_text(aes(y = 1 - lab.y.mid, label = ind), color = "black")
```

But it doesn't appear this command is the last thing that ggplot "did". If you look at the plot above you'll see that my text labels are very faint. The text is either behind some of the sections of the plot, or it has inherited some type of alpha level, or something else is going on I haven't thought of.

How do I get the text to be dark (like it is normally)? Like this plot below.

[image: dark crisp clear text on graph]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`geom_text` inherits the `alpha` aesthetic from `ggplot()` which is the reason the text doesn't appear in "black".

Change your last line to

```
...  + 
  geom_text(aes(x = variable, y = 1 - lab.y.mid, label = ind), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

To get this result

[image]

---

Another option is to overwrite `alpha`

```
... +
geom_text(aes(y = 1 - lab.y.mid, label = ind), alpha = 1)
```

Comment: Was about to post exactly this. If you don't want to reset the `x` variable in `aes()` you can always set `alpha = 1` in `geom_text(aes(...), alpha = 1)`

Comment: @dylanjm Sorry ... Included the second approach at the end.